# Show and tell for unlearned rabbits

Tags: rabbits, breeding

I have been asked if one of my baby rabbits could be used for a story time.  The babies will be 4 weeks old at that time.  Is it safe to temporarily remove a kit from the litter and return it soon after or will the mother kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience it is safe, at 4 weeks old they are not quite small, and the mother never rejected them even though we pick up the babies almost daily.

It is not just me:
[Newborn Baby Rabbit Care](http://www.thenaturetrail.com/rabbit-breeding/care-newborn-baby-bunny/)